# Components Input Won't reset to 0 when Cleared from 0

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a weird scenario. I created a small component that allows a user to enter a value and then increment/decrement.

When the user backspaces out the value I want it to reset it to zero. For some reason if it is any other number than 0 and I hit backspace it fills it with 0. But when it's 0 and I hit backspace it stays blank instead of filling in a 0 in it's place.

Here is the small .ts file

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-incrementer',
  templateUrl: './incrementer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./incrementer.component.scss'],
})
export class IncrementerComponent implements OnInit {

  decrementOff: any
  incrementOff: any;

  @Input('value') value: any;
  @Input('max') max: any;
  @Input('min') min: any;
  @Input('step') step: any;
  @Input('heading') heading: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  changed() {
    // If the user decides to delete the number, we will set it to 0.
    if (!this.value) {
      this.value = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ion-card style="background-color: white">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="3"></ion-col>
        <ion-col size="6" class="heading"> {{heading}}</ion-col>
        <ion-col size="3"></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="3" (click)="decrement()">
          <ion-icon name="caret-down-circle"></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="6">
          <ion-input class="incrementer-field" type="tel" class="counter-field" [(ngModel)]="value"
            (ionChange)="changed()" [readonly]="readonly"></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="3" disabled (click)="increment()">
          <ion-icon name="caret-up-circle"></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

[image]

So like I said, when it's 0 like above and I hit backspace it just leaves it blank. Any other number and backspace it refills the box with 0 as expected.

Comment: Presuming this is not a code fragment, you are missing a form tag and readonly is not an attribute of ion-input.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is to always keep 0 as the min value in the input field, then I would rather not allow user to remove 0. So, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
onType(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Backspace' && this.value === 0) {
      return false
    }
}
```

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" (keydown)="onType($event)" (ngModelChange)="updateColon()">
```

Here's a simple [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-t5r8kv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)